# mysql_query returned from other function not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this situation and I can't figure out why it is not working. I bet that it is simple, but I just can't find solution.

This is first file:

```
$result = query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE something=1 LIMIT 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo $row[0];
```

this is query function from second file:

```
function query($query){
    return mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error());
}
```

Error I get is:

```
mysql_fetch_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

@ line where

```
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
```

is.

So, quite simple, why this is not working like this, and is working when I replace

```
$result = query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE something=1 LIMIT 1");
```

with

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE something=1 LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: What do you get if you var_dump($result) in both cases?

Comment: Yes, they had variables in them, but I echoed $query after passing and it was good. Something else was the problem, I don't know why and how, but I've solved it.

Comment: Don't write answers in questions.

Comment: Sorry, I've solved it before I got answer, so that was logic to me. So, if I answer my own question, I have to write an answer to myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `query` function to

```
function query( $query ){

    $result = mysql_query( $query );
    if ( $result === FALSE ){
        die( mysql_error() );
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to get this error a lot when I first started programming.  The most typical reasons I would get this would be because the database connection wasn't initialized, or because I was calling the wrong version of mysql/sql/mysqli.  Aside from that, making sure everything is spelled correctly in your query is key.

One of the things I would do to test would be to take my query with a sample set of real values, and run it in phpmyadmin and see if it was successful.  If it was, it's likely due to lack of a proper db connection.

Comment: Yea, I've been through all of that, I'm not really a beginner, it was just very uncommon mistake that confused me.